# Drawing my own object on a layout: problem with subclassing gtk.drawable

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to draw my own object on a layout, so I'm trying to subclass gdk.drawable,

```
class link(gtk.gdk.Drawable):
  def __init__(self,comp1,comp2,layout):
      super(link, self).__init__()
      self.x1=comp1.xpos
      self.y1=comp1.ypos
      self.x2=comp2.xpos
      self.y2=comp2.ypos
      self.layout=layout
```

error:

> cannot create instance of abstract (non-instantiable) type `GdkDrawable'

I can do it without subclassing drawable using layout.bin_window.draw_line() in a method drawlink() of my link object, but I'm not able to create a custom graphic context gdk.gc for each object and I have to use the layout.get_style() which will be the same for all my links!

```
  def drawlink(self):
    gc = self.layout.get_style().fg_gc[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
    gc.line_style=gtk.gdk.LINE_ON_OFF_DASH
    gc.line_width=6
    self.layout.bin_window.draw_line(gc,self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)
```

this is the reason I want to subclass drawable. if I can use a custom gc without subclassing drawable or(window, pixmap) it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any alternative?

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is not subclassing `gtk.gdk.Drawable` but populating a **[`gtk.DrawingArea`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkdrawingarea.html) widget** with your own content. The description of that widget is:

> The `gtk.DrawingArea` widget is used for creating custom user interface elements. It's essentially a blank widget containing a `gtk.gdk.Window` that you can draw on.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to draw a line (link) to connect 2 objects comp1 and comp2, these two objects are subclassed from button, I don't need any window. If this is the only way, is it possible to make the rectangular window transparent so it only shows the link?(I'm drawing on a layout)

Comment: @Openl - you need a top level container for your widgets (window, dialogue). Opacity of the window can be set with [set_opacity](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-opacity).

Comment: I can do it including layout.bin_window.draw_line() in a method drawlink() of my link object, but I'm not able to create a custom grafic context gdk.gc and I have to use the layout.get_style() which will be the same for all my links! that is the reason I wanted to subclass drawable. if I can use a custom gc without subclassing drawable or(window, pixmap) it would be great. so thank you for your patence but I realy prefere your approach as a last resort (please tell me if you know your solution is the best available)

Comment: @Openl - In this job you never finish learning, so I wouldn't trust anybody who would say "I'm sure it's the best way"! ;) That said, I am not in any way an expert in PyGTK. I think the problem you are bumping into might be due to the fact PyGTK is just a wrapper around the C libs, so in the process you lose a lot of flexibility. It might well be that in C your solution would be straightforward to implement... Sorry my answer was not useful to you. :-|

Comment: I'll keep trying/searching and finally I may use your solution which is valid :) thank you!